# How to clean double lines from joint statement in R?

Tags: r, left-join, subset

Having done a join operation to compare addresses with itself.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(stringdist)
library(fuzzyjoin)
doTheJoin <- function (threshold) {
      joined <- trimData(d_client_squashed) %>% 
        stringdist_left_join(
          trimData(d_client_squashed), 
          by = c(address_full="address_full"),
          distance_col = "distance",
          max_dist = threshold,
          method = "jw"
        )
    }
```

The structure of d_client_squashed is the following and contains string values:

| Client_Reference | adress_full |
| --- | --- |
| C01 | Client1 Name, Street, Zipcode, Town |
| C02 | Client2 Name, Street2, Zipcode2, Town2 |
| ... | ... |

The following operation:

```
sensible_matches <- doTheJoin(0.2)
View(sensible_matches %>% filter(Client_Reference.x != Client_Reference.y))
```

Results in the following output:

| Client_Reference.x | address_full.x | Client_Reference.y | address_full.y | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C01 | Client1 Name, Street, Zipcode, Town | C02 | Client2 Name, Street2, Zipcode2, Town2 | 0.05486 |
| C02 | Client2 Name, Street2, Zipcode2, Town2 | C01 | Client1 Name, Street, Zipcode, Town | 0.05486 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The output of this join operation is double with reversed client information. The distance value is not unique. How can I subset the data frame to avoid those double lines?

Comment: What is your desired output?  You've filtered on `(Client_Reference.x != Client_Reference.y)`, so your sample is what I would expect.  Does `(Client_Reference.x == Client_Reference.y) give you what you want?

Comment: The overall goal is to get a list with addresses that are similar in order to identify double entries that have spelling errors or differences like "Bachstr. 5" and "Bach Street 5" are supposed to be the same. With (Client_Reference.x != Client_Reference.y) i wanted to avoid having compared a Client address by itsself. The goal for the requested operation is to get rid of the 2nd line that has the same Distance value but the The Client_Reference.x and Client_Reference.y are just inverted. So its a double result that i want to remove from the list in order to not validate it twice.

Comment: Give each line a rownumber .. and then just work on couples (i,j) where rownumer.i > rownumber.j ..

Comment: what about `Client_Reference.x > Client_Reference.y` instead of `Client_Reference.x != Client_Reference.y`

Comment: @Waldi I really like that attempt. Unluckily this solution struggles on not being able to apply the comparison on the Client_Reference.x and .y as these are factors.

Comment: You could perhaps convert to character : `as.character(Client_Reference.x) > as.character( Client_Reference.y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to remove the rows containing the same data, you can order them based on the contained elements, so there is not difference between rows containing the same pair of `Client_Reference`, and then delete the duplicates. After that you can filter the ones containing the same `Client_Reference` as you did.

```
sensible_matches <- sensible_matches[!duplicated(t(apply(sensible_matches,1,sort))),]
View(sensible_matches  %>% filter(Client_Reference.x != Client_Reference.y))
```

Comment: This perfectly solves the request. Thank you!